# How to alternate image on left/right using "Views Parity Row" module

Tags: views

This great tutorial explains everything except the CSS work.
http://gogrow.org/tutorials/views_parity_row

I need to add CSS class to each row so I can set left/right alignment accordingly in css style.
Views settings allows me to set the ccs class in `Page: Style options` but this one is always the same for each row. I need the class name also to alternate.

I need something like dynamically use the `View Mode` as css class name.

Current output: `<div class="views-row">`
Desired output: `<div class="views-row left">` and `<div class="views-row right">`

Or am I missing something and the CSS work is done in a complete different way?

Comment: You could try using `.views-row:nth-child(even) { ... }` and `.views-row:nth-child(odd){ ... }`, **[see example](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_nth-child_odd_even).**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just set all view-rows to be left and then do like this in your css:

```
.views-row:nth-child(2) {
   float: right;
}
```

UPDATE:

```
.views-row:nth-child(odd) {
  float: left;
}
 .views-row:nth-child(even) {
  float: right;
}
```

As @No Sssweat pointed out you can use nth-child odd and even to style every second element. You don’t need to style on the parent just use above code.

I actually wrote something wrong you can add nth-child on the .views-row elements

Comment: I was thinking of such solution too. Currently I have problem that basic theme has single parent with class "js-view-dom-id-64eb3c1702d4342adfdcc75d1bd5d7cab00b4090e16aed1e192df3ef97da623a". This is clearly a no-permanent id. I have no clue what this is for and what am I going to break if I remove it.

Comment: Try to take a look at updated answer